# New Android App failing on repeated launch

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-maps

I'm running through [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start#maps_android_mapsactivity-kotlin) on building an android app with google maps built in. The first run I made was successful, but when I run the same thing successively, it crashes and cannot load.

Included here are the log for the successful run, and from the unsuccessful run:

```
- a non-exiting runtime exception
- the fatal unimplemented / null object reference exception
- a log about accessing hidden fields that's much longer than the equivalent message in the "correct" log
```

I'm unsure about what data is necessary, but there's a size limit on these questions, so let me know if there's any other info that could be helpful here.

Successful Launch:

```
01/01 13:45:52: Launching 'app' on Pixel 4 API 30.
Install successfully finished in 578 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.zellishstories/com.example.zellishstories.MapsActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 12703 on device 'Pixel_4_API_30 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/.zellishstorie: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
I/.zellishstorie: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/.zellishstorie: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/.zellishstorie: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
D/MapsInitializer: preferredRenderer: null
D/zzca: preferredRenderer: null
I/zzca: Making Creator dynamically
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:201817000
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 201817000
V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
W/.zellishstorie: Unsupported class loader
W/.zellishstorie: Unsupported class loader
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
D/MapsInitializer: loadedRenderer: LEGACY
D/zzca: preferredRenderer: null
I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 201817022
I/TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:com.example.zellishstories
W/.zellishstorie: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf0c2eae0, tid 12733
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf0c2e370: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf0c2e370: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf0f7d8b0) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf0c2df10, tid 12733
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3f3ffe000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf0c2cf50, tid 12765
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_has_shared_slots_host_memory_allocator ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data ANDROID_EMU_read_color_buffer_dma GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf0c2db20: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
W/Gralloc4: allocator 3.x is not supported
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf0c2db20: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xf0f7df70) (first time)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf0c2db20: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0xf0f7df70) (first time)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/.zellishstorie: Unsupported class loader
W/.zellishstorie: Unsupported class loader
```

Runtime Exception:

```
W/Resources: Drawable com.example.zellishstories:drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_material has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getDrawable(int, Theme) or Context.getDrawable(int).
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:899)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.at.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):6)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.r.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):30)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bi.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):19)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.co.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):21)
        at cy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzH(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:7)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zad.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:386)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:140)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:319)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:298)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:657)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.example.zellishstories.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(ActivityMapsBinding.java:36)
        at com.example.zellishstories.databinding.ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(ActivityMapsBinding.java:30)
        at com.example.zellishstories.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.kt:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5362)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2076)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Fatal Exception:

```
D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 809
    Process: com.example.zellishstories, PID: 12961
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):11)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):3)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.g.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):23)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bt.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):20)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201817052@20.18.17 (040700-0):56)
```

Weird hidden access note:

```
Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->EMPTY_STACK_TRACE:[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->SUBCLASS_IMPLEMENTATION_PERMISSION:Ljava/lang/RuntimePermission; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->lock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->daemon:Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->threadLocals:Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->inheritableThreadLocals:Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;J)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
```

Comment: can you send the piece of code which uses `abc_ic_voice_search_api_material`

Answer (score 0):

From what is seems in the Fatal Exception where it reads

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

at line 4, you try to get the width of a drawable which is loaded to null (probably an ImageView not defined (correctly) in the xml file).
Can you verify that all Views are defined correctly?